# Remove special character

Tags: python, text

How do I convert input text `'abcde'f gh'`to output `'abcdefgh'`?

This did not work.

```
a='abcde'f gh'
b=a.translate({(u"\u0027"):None})
```

Comment: Your first line would cause a SyntaxError; also, please include the errors you got

Comment: "All characters are special."  If you mean for the string to include a literal apostrophe, maybe actually explain this.

Comment: Made question more concise. But the original comments apply; the OP should probably check the string assigned to `a`.

Answer (score 0):

You should escape the apostrophe `'` or use the quotes `"` to define the string:

```
>> a='abcde\'f gh'
```

or

```
>> a="abcde'f gh"
```

To remove the symbol `'` and the spaces, use `string.translate` like this:

```
>> b = a.translate(None," \'")
'abcdefgh'
```

> *string.translate(s, table[, deletechars])*
>
> Delete all characters from s that are in deletechars (if present), and then translate the characters using table, which must be a 256-character string giving the translation for each character value, indexed by its ordinal. If table is None, then only the character deletion step is performed.